# Hijack Syscall: Access system call arguments from struct pt_regs (64bit-x86)

Tags: c, linux-kernel, hook, system-calls, kprobe

Using kprobes pre_handler, I am trying to access the system call arguments from struct pt_regs and modify them(which is the main goal), before calling the actual system call itself.

Say I am probing `sys_link`.

```
asmlinkage long sys_link(const char __user *oldname, const char __user *newname);
```

The pre_handler is defined as follows:(from [here](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~boutcher/kprobes/))

```
static int handler_pre(struct kprobe *p, struct pt_regs *regs)
{
     printk(KERN_INFO "eax: %08lx   ebx: %08lx   ecx: %08lx   edx: %08lx\n",
            regs->orig_ax, regs->bx, regs->cx, regs->dx);
     printk(KERN_INFO "esi: %08lx   edi: %08lx   ebp: %08lx   esp: %08lx\n",
            regs->si, regs->di, regs->bp, regs->sp);
     printk(KERN_INFO "Process %s (pid: %d, threadinfo=%p task=%p)",
             current->comm, current->pid, current_thread_info(), current);
return 0;
}
```

When I run `link file1 file2` on the terminal, dmesg gives the following output:

```
[15105.691463] eax: ffffffffffffffff   ebx: 7fff3e2e71c8   ecx: 7fff3e2e6e50   edx: 00000003
[15105.691467] esi: 7fff3e2e9478   edi: 7fff3e2e9472   ebp: 00000003   esp: ffff880022b0ff80
[15105.691472] Process link (pid: 9448, threadinfo=ffff880022b0e000 task=ffff880018b72e00)Pid: 9448, comm: link Tainted: P         C O 3.2.0-53-generic #81-Ubuntu
```

The first two arguments go to registers `edi` and `esi`, therefore in this case, `edi` must contain address of `file1` and `esi` must contain address of `file2`.

I want to modify these register values, say change the value in `esi` to point to `file3` (therefore the char __user *newname is now pointing to `file3`), before I return from the pre_handler. Given such a modification, now `sys_link` should work with `file1` and `file3` as its arguments.
Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Why not to use `jprobes`?

Comment: The link you have posted wonderfully explains all the three types of debug handlers you can insert into the kernel. I don't see what you are missing. As for your question, using jprobes will do instead of using raw kprobes. Please post why you want to use raw kprobes instead of jprobes and what's the problem you are facing in using them.

Comment: @IlyaMatveychikov,@VivekS: jprobes wouldn't allow modifying the system call arguments(ie. struct pt_regs), it restores the original argument values immediately after returning from the pre_handler, and before calling the actual syscall, I believe.